# User defined type not defined in vba factorytalk view

Tags: vba, scada

I am new to VBA code, and working on a SCADA system where VBA code is required. I am having VBA code that need to be imported but getting errors as "User Defined Tags not Defined". Please tell me where I am wrong in the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Private lstRecHeader As ColumnHeader        ' Headers in the lstReceived
Private lstRecItems As ListItem             ' Items in the lstReceived
Private lstRecSubItems As ListSubItem
```

Getting error on the part  **Private lstRecHeader As ColumnHeader**

Comment: Where are you getting these objects? Are you reading a tutorial? If so, where is it?

Comment: No. I am not using Tutorial. This code is written for one the "Forms".  This code is already written in the older SCADA system (RSView 32) and its working fine. I have imported this in the new SCADA system (FactoryTalk View), so I am assuming there must be some different syntax or different way to write it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/How-to/user-defined-type-not-defined I guess the cause is _The type is a valid type, but the object library or type library in which it is defined isn't registered in Visual Basic._